# Python function that returns tail of list

Tags: python, list, function, cdr

Does there exist a python *function* that returns the tail of a list?
For the purposes of doing something succinct like:

```py
>>> triplets = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
>>> [cdr(t) for t in triplets]
[[2,3],[2,3],[2,3]]
```

**N.B.** This is a different scenario that does not call for *in-place* operators mentioned in similar questions - the comprehension here would fail, as these methods do not *return* a mutated list.

Comment: List comprehension is probably the way to go on this one.

Comment: Thanks - re the downvotes - just to mention, I'm specifically asking whether or not a  _function_ exists for the above purposes.

Comment: from the linked answer: you can do `.pop(0)` to remove the first element.

Comment: That can't be used in the above comprehension however.

Comment: You're right - `.pop()` does the operation in-place. I guess slicing works.

Comment: Of course you can make a function if you must like `def cdr(t): return t[1:]`

Comment: @category *sigh* have you actually read the linked page? You only needed to scroll to the second answer to learn about slicing.

Comment: Yep, it's actually given as the 6th answer. Had to scroll right down to see it, but fair enough - it's there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list slicing :

```
>>> triplets = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
>>> [t[1:] for t in triplets]
[[2,3],[2,3],[2,3]]
```

Comment: I think you should get rid of the `>>>` on the third line as to avoid confusion between user input and output. Just a quick note :)

Comment: Done, question has been edited.